# How to fix corrupted permissions inside encfs encrypted folder

Tags: mount, encryption, chmod, chown, encfs

I manage and mount a encrypted folder with Gnome encfs manager and it worked for years. Suddenly it seems like the files or permissions inside were corrupted. Mounting works as usual on terminal as with the manager. The files in the root folder also are accessible.

But in all child directories I only see the filename permissions as question marks, can't open them and even with sudo cannot change permissions.

```
root@lubuntu:/home/user/safe# ls -l   
    ls: cannot access local: Permission denied
    total 1932
    ...
    d????????? ? ?      ?           ?            ? local
```

local is the mounted encfs encrypted folder. On a root shell I cannot cd inside, with my own user I can but only get question marks again:

```
[~/safe/local/backup]$ ls -l
ls: cannot access index.htm: Permission denied
ls: cannot access bookmarks.html: Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?                ? foo/
-????????? ? ? ? ?                ? index.html
-????????? ? ? ? ?                ? bookmarks.htm
```

The weird thing is with my user I can access the files in ~/safe/local/ fine but nothing in it's subdirectories, and root can do even less. chown and chmod give me "Permission denied" as root or with sudo.

Any advice? Does that hint at a failing hard drive?
I very recently updated from Lubuntu 14.10 to 15.10.

Update: Here is the verbose output when mounting:

```
[~/safe]$ encfs -f -v  .local test
14:37:17 (main.cpp:559) Root directory: .local/
14:37:17 (main.cpp:560) Fuse arguments: (fg) (threaded) (keyCheck) encfs test -f -o use_ino 
14:37:17 (FileUtils.cpp:174) version = 20
14:37:17 (FileUtils.cpp:177) found new serialization format
14:37:17 (FileUtils.cpp:191) subVersion = 20100713
14:37:17 (Interface.cpp:117) checking if ssl/aes(3:0:2) implements ssl/aes(3:0:0)
14:37:17 (SSL_Cipher.cpp:335) allocated cipher ssl/aes, keySize 32, ivlength 16
14:37:17 (Interface.cpp:117) checking if ssl/aes(3:0:2) implements ssl/aes(3:0:0)
14:37:17 (SSL_Cipher.cpp:335) allocated cipher ssl/aes, keySize 32, ivlength 16
14:37:17 (FileUtils.cpp:1542) useStdin: 0
EncFS Password: 
14:37:22 (Interface.cpp:117) checking if ssl/aes(3:0:2) implements ssl/aes(3:0:0)
14:37:22 (SSL_Cipher.cpp:335) allocated cipher ssl/aes, keySize 32, ivlength 16
14:37:24 (FileUtils.cpp:1550) cipher key size = 52
14:37:24 (Interface.cpp:117) checking if nameio/block(4:0:2) implements nameio/block(3:0:0)
14:37:24 (MACFileIO.cpp:71) fs block size = 1024, macBytes = 8, randBytes = 0
14:37:24 (FileNode.cpp:116) calling setIV on (null)
14:37:24 (RawFileIO.cpp:164) getAttr error on .local/uWX6wZAqMvH5RDRMW5oIb67F8V6CoVXYZPwUf6bHbu1Ms0: No such file or directory
14:37:24 (CipherFileIO.cpp:94) in setIV, current IV = 0, new IV = 11696676665880040319, fileIV = 0
14:37:24 (DirNode.cpp:641) created FileNode for .local/uWX6wZAqMvH5RDRMW5oIb67F8V6CoVXYZPwUf6bHbu1Ms0
14:37:24 (encfs.cpp:133) getattr .local/uWX6wZAqMvH5RDRMW5oIb67F8V6CoVXYZPwUf6bHbu1Ms0
14:37:24 (RawFileIO.cpp:164) getAttr error on .local/uWX6wZAqMvH5RDRMW5oIb67F8V6CoVXYZPwUf6bHbu1Ms0: No such file or directory
14:37:24 (encfs.cpp:136) getattr error: No such file or directory
14:37:24 (MACFileIO.cpp:71) fs block size = 1024, macBytes = 8, randBytes = 0
14:37:24 (FileNode.cpp:116) calling setIV on (null)
14:37:24 (RawFileIO.cpp:164) getAttr error on .local/kbZ-jP1BAg0-VpqtlMjAKr9F: No such file or directory
14:37:24 (CipherFileIO.cpp:94) in setIV, current IV = 0, new IV = 17358762804478769995, fileIV = 0
14:37:24 (DirNode.cpp:641) created FileNode for .local/kbZ-jP1BAg0-VpqtlMjAKr9F
(continues like that...)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen those kinds of errors before, while testing out EncFS & eCryptFS actually, but I didn't remember exactly where I'd seen it until now. It was from not having permission to read or list files in the directory (directories need `x` execute permission to list files), and I think it could've happened with a decrypt error too.

I had some issues with permissions in mounted/decrypted files before. They seemed to reflect only the permissions of the encrypted file (EncFS man page calls it the "rootdir"), and changing the mounted/decrypted files didn't seem to work. Maybe the owner & permissions for the "rootdir" / encrypted files aren't correct? Try changing the "rootdir"/encrypted permissions so your user can access them (rwx?).

I thought root should be able to read anything no matter what... but encfs doesn't need sudo to run, and I tried a test with a single encrypted folder `secret` and it's decrypted mountpoint `open` and the same thing happened:

```
$ ls -go
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 80 Nov 11 00:14 open
drwxr-xr-x 2 80 Nov 11 00:14 secret

$ sudo ls -go
ls: cannot access open: Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ?  ?            ? open
drwxr-xr-x 2 80 Nov 11 00:14 secret
```

Or maybe it's not decrypting the files correctly. If you have a good backup of the data that would be great.

---

I'm thinking the upgrade from 14.10 to 15.10 might be responsible. Sometimes using a newer version with old data doesn't always work well.

The `encfs` package versions I can find on http://packages.ubuntu.com/ are currently:
in wily (15.10) is version 1.8.1-3
in vivid (15.04) is version 1.7.4-5
in 14.10 it's not on the webpage anymore, was probably 1.7.4...
in trusty (14.04LTS) is version 1.7.4-2.4ubuntu2

Or, the `.encfs6.xml` "config file" may have been corrupted somehow. Trying to use a backup copy of it could work. `man encfs` has some details, but looks like it still has references to version 5.

I'd try, in order of preference:

1. Change the permissions of the encrypted folder/files so your user can read them all (& execute the folders, to list files)
2. Try a backup copy of the config file (`.encfs6.xml`) with a command similar to:

   ```
   ENCFS6_CONFIG=/home/me/.encfs6.xml encfs /encryptedDir /decryptedDir
   ```
3. Recover the data from a good backup, and start with a new encfs folder/setup with the latest encfs.
4. Try using an older version of encfs to mount the folder, maybe with a live 14.04LTS

If there are no HD errors (see syslog & maybe even the SMART data) then I wouldn't suspect the HD immediately.

Comment: Thanks a lot, luckily I made a backup before upgrading. It's weird that my new install can mount the backup on the external hd without problems. But I will try mounting with a 14.04 Live CD and see if I can make everything work.

Comment: Hmmm, if the backup was basically identical, then maybe something happened to the `.encfs6.xml` "config" file. If it's an identical / mirror backup, are the `..encfs6.xml` files identical? Or the owner & permissions for the "rootdir" / encrypted files aren't readable? I had some issues with permissions before, they seem to reflect only the root / encrypted file, changing the mounted/decrypted files didn't seem to work. I'll edit the answer a little.

Comment: thanks so much! :) With your hint I first time looked at the actual encrypted folder, not the mounted unencrypted (stupid I know). The .encfs6.xml are identical but permissions were different of subfolders. After I chmodded those 777 they were instantly readable again. I copied the encrypted folder with rsync -avP back on the hard drive after upgrading Lubuntu but seems the permissions still changed. Thanks a lot again! :)